# periodic point of a quadratic map

Tags: difference-equations

I am analyzing a discrete dynamic quadratic map. The bifurcation diagram shows the existence of an asymptotic 3- cycle periodic point for a given parameter. But the graphic of the lyapunov exponent gives a positive coefficient.
My map `quad[{x,y}]` is `{x + K x (2. - 0.76 x - 0.4 y), y + K (2. - 0.6 x - 0.5 y) y}`. I am working on 3-periodic cycle. The bifurcation diagram shoes that there an asymptotic convergent 3-cycle period at the value of the parameter K=`K = 1.417`. When I take the map quad3 and analyze fixed point by writing  `quad3[{x_, y_}] = Simplify[quad[quad[quad[{x, y}]]]];` and then : `FindRoot[quad3[{x, y}] == {x, y}, {{x, 1.85}, {y, 2.96}}]`. I obtain `{x -> 1.85234, y -> 2.96374}` hence `x=1.8523360794543522` and `y=2.9637377271382412`. When writing `x = 1.8523360794543522; y = 2.9637377271382412;` and `quad3[{x, y}]` I obtain `x=1.8523360794681456` and `y=2.9637377271328504`. there is small difference. How to be sure that the fixed point of quad3 exits or equivalently a 3-period cycle exists ?

Comment: What have you tried? What is your code? And can you try to give a specific question, too.

Comment: My map f[{x,y}] is {x + K x (2. - 0.76 x - 0.4 y), y + K (2. - 0.6 x - 0.5 y) y}. I am working on 3-periodic cycle. The bifurcation diagram shoes that there an asymptotic convergent 3-cycle period at the value of the parameter K=K = 1.417. When I take the map f3 and analyze fixed point by

Comment: You could try increasing the [`WorkingPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html) of `FindRoot`. See also [`AccuracyGoal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AccuracyGoal.html) and [`PrecisionGoal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrecisionGoal.html).

Comment: How'd you get the bifurcation diagram and Lyapunov exponents?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the 3-cycle you found at `K=1.417` is stable.  Here are two lines of evidence:

First, simulate the map (warmup for 100 steps, then plot the next 20) and see:

```
quad[{x_, y_}] := {x + K x (2. - 0.76 x - 0.4 y), y + K (2. - 0.6 x - 0.5 y) y};
K=1.417;
ListLinePlot[Transpose[NestList[quad, Nest[quad, {1.85, 3}, 100], 20]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Doesn't seem to be settling down to a cycle.

Second, find the eigenvalues of the Jacobian matrix of the 3-step map `quad3`:

```
quad3[{x_, y_}] = Simplify[quad[quad[quad[{x, y}]]]];
j3 := D[quad3[{x, y}], {{x, y}, 1}]
eq3 = FindRoot[quad3[{x, y}] == {x, y}, {{x, 1.85}, {y, 2.96}}]
(* {x -> 1.85234, y -> 2.96374} *)
Eigenvalues[j3 /. eq3]
(* {-1.42176, -0.280642} *)
```

The eigenvalue of `-1.42176` indicates instability of the 3-cycle `eq3`.

One last idea: simulate starting near the unstable 3-cycle to watch the divergence.

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose[NestList[quad, {x + 10^-4, y} /. eq3, 100]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]